# How to detect if my program enters a self-deadlock?

Tags: c++, mutex, deadlock

I have multi-threaded program and it only has 1 mutex. I want to make the program terminate if it attempts to grab the lock if it already has it.

My actual program is pretty complicated. Of course we try to avoid deadlocks on a programming level. But just in case we miss a edge case, we prefer it to fail immediately rather than deadlock.

See a minimal example below.

```
std::mutex lock;

void f1() {
    std::lock_guard<mutex> guard1(lock);
    // some code ...
}

void f2() {
    std::lock_guard<mutex> guard2(lock);  
    f1(); // Will deadlock here! How can I make it terminate instead of deadlock?
}
```

Comment: How have you wound up in this situation? It might be better to rethink the program logic so that it can't happen. Wait a second. This is just simplified example. Never mind.  Ignore the ranting old fool.

Comment: Being pedantic but... your assertion that the same thread locking an `std::mutex` multiple times `"Will deadlock..."` is incorrect.  Strictly speaking it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @G.M. "*Strictly speaking it's undefined behaviour*" - unless a recursive mutex is used, then it is well-defined.

Comment: @RemyLebeau True, but the code shown uses `std::mutex lock;`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::mutex` provides no mechanism for accomplishing what you describe.

Instead of deadlock detection, you should be looking at deadlock avoidance.  Careful programming, including appropriate choice of mutex role and scope, can help.  Refactoring could help, too. For example, you could change your example code to

```
std::mutex lock;

static void f1_impl() {
    // some code ...
}

void f1() {
    std::lock_guard<mutex> guard1(lock);
    f1_impl();
}

void f2() {
    std::lock_guard<mutex> guard2(lock);  
    f1_impl();
}
```

But if that doesn't get you all the way to where you want to be, then you might want to consider using `std::recursive_mutex` instead of `std::mutex`.  That addresses the problem by allowing a thread that already holds the mutex locked to lock it again.

Comment: "*you could avoid the deadlock by using `std::mutex::try_lock()` instead of `std::mutex::lock()`*" - `try_lock()` has **undefined behavior** when called on a mutex that is already locked by the calling thread, as is the case in the OP's example.

Comment: Offending comments removed, @RemyLebeau.  The answer didn't need them anyway.

Comment: My actual use case is: our program currently uses `std::recursive_lock` and we have to be very careful about making it re-enterable. We've refactored some code and we think that `std::recursive_lock` is no longer needed. We want to replace it with `std::mutex` but we prefer it to fail immediately if it self deadlocks.

Comment: As I already said, @YixingLiu, `std::mutex` does not afford that possibility.  However, you might be able to write a custom wrapper for a system mutex primitive that does the wanted job.  For example, pthread mutexes can be configured such that attempts by the same thread to re-lock them cause an error instead of deadlocking.  Your wrapper would detect that and respond appropriately - by throwing an exception, for example, or even by terminating the program.  But this relies on various assumptions about your C++ implementation.

Comment: Thank you @JohnBollinger It is also helpful to know what `std::mutex` is incapable of.